# ETL project, handling XML, CSV, and text files

Tags: object-oriented, csv, xml, vb.net

I have completed an ETL project to collect, parse and load files. I decided to make it clean OOP way using interfaces and abstract, but have some questions below.

```
Sub Main()

        Dim collectionOfParsers As New List(Of EtlParser)
        Dim xmlparser1 As New XmlParser
        Dim xmlparser2 As New XmlParser
        Dim xmlparser3 As New XmlParser
        Dim txtparser1 As New TxtParser
        Dim txtparser2 As New TxtParser

        collectionOfParsers.Add(xmlparser1)
        collectionOfParsers.Add(xmlparser2)
        collectionOfParsers.Add(xmlparser3)
        collectionOfParsers.Add(txtparser1)
        collectionOfParsers.Add(txtparser2)


        For Each parser As EtlParser In collectionOfParsers

            parser.SaySomething()

            Dim canOpenFiles = TryCast(parser, ICanOpenFiles)
            If (canOpenFiles IsNot Nothing) Then
                canOpenFiles.OpenFiles()
            End If

            Dim canReadFiles = TryCast(parser, ICanReadFiles)
            If (canReadFiles IsNot Nothing) Then
                canReadFiles.Readfiles()
            End If

            Dim canTransFiles = TryCast(parser, ICanTransformFiles)
            If (canTransFiles IsNot Nothing) Then
                canTransFiles.TransformFile()
            End If

            Dim canSaveFiles = TryCast(parser, ICanSaveFiles)
            If (canSaveFiles IsNot Nothing) Then
                canSaveFiles.Savefiles()
            End If

        Next
    End Sub

       Public MustInherit Class Etl
        End Class

        Public MustInherit Class EtlParser : Inherits Etl
                Protected Sub CanParse()
                    Console.WriteLine("Yes")
                End Sub

         Protected Overridable Sub SaySomething()
                Console.WriteLine("EtlParser say something")
            End Sub

                Protected MustOverride Sub CanParseFormat()
        End Class

        Public Interface ICanOpenFiles
                Sub OpenFiles()
        End Interface

        Public Interface ICanReadFiles
                Sub Readfiles()
        End Interface

        Public Interface ICanSaveFiles
                Sub Savefiles()
        End Interface

        Public Interface ICanTransformFiles
                Sub TransformFile()
        End Interface

          Public Class XmlParser : Inherits EtlParser
                Implements ICanOpenFiles, ICanReadFiles, ICanTransformFiles, ICanSaveFiles

                Public Sub OpenFiles() Implements ICanOpenFiles.OpenFiles
                    Throw New NotImplementedException()
                End Sub

                Public Sub Readfiles() Implements ICanReadFiles.Readfiles
                    Throw New NotImplementedException()
                End Sub

                Public Sub TransformFile() Implements ICanTransformFiles.TransformFile
                    Throw New NotImplementedException()
                End Sub

                Public Sub Savefiles() Implements ICanSaveFiles.Savefiles
                    Throw New NotImplementedException()
                End Sub

                Protected Overrides Sub CanParseFormat()
                    Throw New NotImplementedException()
                End Sub

     Protected Overrides Sub SaySomething()
                'MyBase.SaySomething()
                Console.WriteLine("XmlParser say something")
            End Sub

            End Class


         Public Class CsvParser : Inherits EtlParser

                Implements ICanOpenFiles, ICanReadFiles, ICanTransformFiles, ICanSaveFiles

                Public Sub OpenFiles() Implements ICanOpenFiles.OpenFiles
                    Throw New NotImplementedException()
                End Sub

                Public Sub Readfiles() Implements ICanReadFiles.Readfiles
                    Throw New NotImplementedException()
                End Sub

                Public Sub TransformFile() Implements ICanTransformFiles.TransformFile
                    Throw New NotImplementedException()
                End Sub

                Public Sub Savefiles() Implements ICanSaveFiles.Savefiles
                    Throw New NotImplementedException()
                End Sub

                Protected Overrides Sub CanParseFormat()
                    Throw New NotImplementedException()
                End Sub

         Protected Overrides Sub SaySomething()
                'MyBase.SaySomething()
                Console.WriteLine("CsvParser say something")
            End Sub

            End Class
```

**Q1:** Once i collect the files from network drive (this will be done by Collector later on). What is your opinion should i make xmlparser class to handle many files or just one? If the second option then as you can see i created already many xmlparser instances (1 instance per each file), however i am not sure here maybe should i have xmlparser prepared for all files and then call it just once?

**Q2:** Regarding the for each loop i parametrized common type as EtlParser to pass diffrent specific parsers (is it ok by the way?). Can you explain me how it's possible specific parser within the loop is seen as passed object type - for instance i passed XmlParser and within i see it as well - i thought that when passing specific parser e.g XmlParser through parameter (his parent - EtlParser) it becomes EtlParser and i have to cast it again to XmlParser again inside loop. Would like to understand that.

**Q3:** As long as i know definition of interfaces e.g "Need to provide common functionality to unrelated classes" what in my example code is real benefit as all of my specific parsers uses the same interfaces at the end? All can open, read, transform and save...

**Q4:** As you see i have 3 specific parser classes: CsvParser, XmlParser, TxtParser inheriting from their base EtlParser class. Wouldn't it be better to make one parser class and instead make interface IXml, ITxt, ICsv which will be implemented? At this moment i think what i have is proper.

**Q5:** Why in the Main method i cannot do: parser.SaySomething() However when i look at parser item it shows exactly correct type.

**Q6:** Any ideas, advices to my current code besides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q1**: It takes nanoseconds to create an object and milliseconds to access a file; i.e. roughly one million times longer! Don't try to optimize things that will have absolutely no noticeable effect at the expense of clarity!

**Q2**: Since `XmlParser` has no methods specific to `XmlParser` (i.e. existing only in `XmlParser`), there is no advantage in casting the object to it. But since the base class `EtlParser` does not implement the interfaces, you must cast the object to these interfaces (what you are doing).

**Q3**, **Q4**, **Q6**: This is one possible approach. I will suggest you another one.

**Q5**: `SaySomething()` is `Protected`, which means that it is only visible within the class defining it and its descendants. Make it `Public`.

---

**Critics**: Your interface makes operations like opening files public. The caller then must know whether this operations is available and call it. But this is a technical implementation detail which should be kept private. A public interface should concentrate on the desired high level logic. I.E. read data, transform data and maybe write data.

**Suggestion**: I would choose a more flexible approach allowing you to compose parsers from single components (like Lego bricks). Define this set of interfaces:

```vb
Public Interface IDataSource(Of T)
    Function Read() As IEnumerable(Of T)
End Interface

Public Interface ITransformer(Of TSource, TResult)
    Function Transform(ByVal source As IEnumerable(Of TSource)) As IEnumerable(Of TResult)
End Interface

Public Interface IDataSink(Of T)
    Sub Write(ByVal data As IEnumerable(Of T))
End Interface
```

The idea is to implement these interfaces by **different** classes. You would have one class for an XML-data-source, one for a file-data-source, one for a transformation, etc.

A data source can be a text-file an XML-file a database or be a dummy data source for test purposes. It is the data source’s responsibility to open, read and close files etc. You don't need separate interfaces for all these operations.

Note that file names and connection strings can be passed as constructor parameters and don't need to be specified in the interfaces.

Define classes serving as transport vehicle for single data records like `RawData`, `PreProcessedData`, `RefinedData` used as generic type arguments for the interfaces. You will probably choose names for these classes that are better suited for your specific problem.

You can even chain several transformations like this:

```vb
read >>(RawData)>> transform 1 >>(PreProcessedData)>> transform 2 >>(RefinedData)>> write
```

One advantage of this approach is that you can apply the same transformations to different types of data sources (having the same `TSource`) and store the result into different types of destinations (having the same `TResult`).

Note: [Iterators (Visual Basic)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/iterators) will help you to implement these interfaces.

---

Let's make a very simple **example**. We have a CSV-File with a name column and two number columns. We want to transform this file into another one containing the name column and one number column containing the sum of the two numbers.

Input file:

> Joe,3,4
>   Mike,6,2
>   Sue,10,3

Expected output file:

> Joe,7
>   Mike,8
>   Sue,13

We need two data classes

```vb
Public Class InputData
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property X As Integer
    Public Property Y As Integer
End Class

Public Class OutputData
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Sum As Integer
End Class
```

A reader

```vb
Public Class ExampleCsvReader
    Implements IDataSource(Of InputData)

    Private m_filename As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal filename As String)
        m_filename = filename
    End Sub

    Public Iterator Function Read() As IEnumerable(Of InputData) _
        Implements IDataSource(Of InputData).Read

        For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(m_filename)
            Dim parts = line.Split(","c)
            If parts.Length = 3 Then
                Yield New InputData With {.Name = parts(0), _
                                          .X = CInt(parts(1)), .Y = CInt(parts(2))}
            End If
        Next
    End Function
End Class
```

A transformer

```vb
Public Class ExampleTransformer
    Implements ITransformer(Of InputData, OutputData)

    Public Iterator Function Transform(source As IEnumerable(Of InputData)) _
        As IEnumerable(Of OutputData) _
        Implements ITransformer(Of InputData, OutputData).Transform

        For Each record As InputData In source
            Yield New OutputData With {.Name = record.Name, .Sum = record.X + record.Y}
        Next
    End Function
End Class
```

A writer

```vb
Public Class ExampleCsvWriter
    Implements IDataSink(Of OutputData)

    Private m_filename As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal filename As String)
        m_filename = filename
    End Sub

    Public Sub Write(data As IEnumerable(Of OutputData)) _
        Implements IDataSink(Of OutputData).Write

        Using sw As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(m_filename)
            For Each record As OutputData In data
                sw.WriteLine($"{record.Name},{record.Sum}")
            Next
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

And finally we can stitch the parts together

```vb
Dim reader = New ExampleCsvReader(inputFile)
Dim transformer = New ExampleTransformer()
Dim writer = New ExampleCsvWriter(outputFile)

Dim inputData = reader.Read()
Dim outputData = transformer.Transform(inputData)
writer.Write(outputData)
```

**Generic solution**: This approach also lets you also realize a more generic solution. You are free to create generic readers that for instance return data in a dictionary. The data type could be a `Dictionary(Of String, Object)` for instance, storing property name/value pairs. A reader could implement a `IDataSource(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))`, for instance.

**VB specific**: The `Yield` statement is like a `Return` statement that returns a value, but unlike the latter, it does not exit the function and continues its execution  to return the next value of the enumeration, and so on, until the end of the function is reached.

Besides [iterators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/iterators) I also used [Object Initializers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/object-initializers-named-and-anonymous-types), [String Interpolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn890368.aspx) (Point 12.), [Using Statement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement).

Comment: First of all thank you very much Olivier for taking your time to help me out. To be honest wit you i read your post x times and can't get full picture of propsoed solution which somehow seems to be very good. What is not clear to me is do you propose to have one class inherits from EtlParser for instnace MainParser for all diffrent sources and implement all your proposed interfaces? Is it what you mean as for now i have XmlParser/CsvParser/TxtParser do you mean to make one for all and implement your interfaces?

Comment: Would it be piossible to extend your answer which could show the whole change to my solution that i could understand fully? I also do not get the iterator approach which could help me out in the solution also would appreciate to get it on example. The best would be also to see where (you mentioned constructors) or how specific file path should be passed and more intresting where specific parser functionality like this for parsing csv's, txt's and database should be placed within solution. If you could put it in one peace i would really appreciate. Thank so much dude !

Comment: Looks nice however you said before that "You would have one class for an XML-data-source, one for a file-data-source.." However from what i see if i will have diffrent csv file than what you shown in example i'd have to implement new class e.g ExampleCsvReaderX so would mean each diffrent file structure is equal to create new ExampleCsvReaderX class and both InputDataX and OutputDataX classes for it. Am i right with this? Also if diffrent transformer new ExampleTransformerX has to be created. If i am not correct can you show based on your example how new diffrent csv file would be implemented?

Comment: P.S I can make new topic if you like. Let me know. I already marked this as an asnwer. Thanks so much Olivier your help is invaluable to me.

Comment: Well, you are free to create generic readers that for instance return data in a dictionary. The data type could be a `Dictionary(Of String, Object)` for instance, storing property name/value pairs.

Comment: I also added a suggestion for a **generic solution** and a **critics**.

Comment: HI Olivier, 1) so i was right that in your first example for me more diffrent files i would need to create for each diffrent one separated ExampleCsvReader_N class with respective InputData and Output Data - please confirm that me to understand this point. 2) Now you propose instead of doing that (1) to go more generic way to keep only one ExampleCsvReader for all diffrent csv files using e.g dictionary is it right thinking? 3) I will sit and try to do something but i think i will have more question to that therefore i  create new topic instead of making this one too long. I'll let youknow her

Comment: It is difficult to answer your questions, since I neither know the stucture of your different files, nor do I know the transformation logic you want to apply and if the generic approch is possible in your case. There are cases where a specific logic must be applied and a generic approach is not possible and others where a genearal logic can be applied in a generic way. It's up to you to decide. Note that you can still create base classes implementing these interfaces and derive more specific ones.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65779/discussion-between-arie-and-olivier-jacot-descombes).